# Outlook settings for office 365 from imap

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, imap

I will be changing from my current mail provider (which uses IMAP) to O365 business premium and will have to transfer my domain etc, which is fine.

There are 2 of us and I'm just not sure how I update outlook and retain all of my mail and calendar items etc. Can I just go into Outlook Account Settings and change the connection settings to O365?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuantely the two accounts you have are significantly different and you will experience considerable difficulty attempting to simply change the mail settings.

We also do not know whether your current email is Exchagne-based (but configured for IMAP) or if it's, say, an alterntive technology (such as any Linux mail server).

The best approach will be to export your existing mailbox to a PST (ensuring you check each option to ensure mailbox, calendar, contacts are contained in the export), create a new Outlook profile and configure it to work with Office 365 and then you can import the existing IMAP PST file into your new Office 365 profile.

I have done a number of such scenarios and the quickest approach is what I describe. It also mitigates data loss as the existing data is left intact.

Comment: Thanks Kinnectus, only problem is I can't create a new profile as it has the exact same email address and outlook complains that it already exists - therefore I'd have to delete the profile to create the new one?

Comment: @John   You seems to add email to one profile. To add a new profile, go to Control Panel > Mail > Show Profiles > Add